# Show that $\left [ 0,1 \right )$ is homeomorphic to $\left ( 0,1 \right ]$.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Question:
>
> Show that $\left [ 0,1 \right )$ is homeomorphic to $\left ( 0,1 \right ]$.

I know what the definition of homeomorphism is. However, the prove seems to require more advanced theorems.

Would

> Theorem:
>   Let X and Y be homeomorphic topological space and let $x \in X$. Then there exists $y \in Y$ such that $X \setminus \left \{ x \right \}$ is homeomorphic to $Y \setminus \left \{ y \right \}$ suffice?

Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Consider $f(x)=1-x$

Answer (score 4):

Well think of how you would translate the first to the second, you can flip it $f(x)=-x$ and then move it $g(x)=1+f(x)=1-x$

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to construct functions?

Comment: @Mathematicing You are supposed to prove two spaces are homeomorphic, i.e. there exists a homeomorphism between them. What easier way to prove existence of certain type of function is there than constructing it explicitly?

Comment: I much prefer using axioms and theorems. I just find that easier..

Comment: No. Mathematics is intuition backed up by axioms and theorems. Your intuition about the concepts aid you in proofs. You'll be stuck forever if you just sift through theorems and axioms and remain disconnected from the actual abstract concepts themselves. It's like trying to push a cart with square wheels. You'll get hung up too often. Theorems and axioms are important, but they are only there as a backbone for your intuition: they come only during the last part of a given thought process in mathematics.

Comment: Also, if you can't reason about the concepts themselves and gain a feel for them the way you can play a movie or a sport in your head, then you'll hit a brick wall when trying to do research. You make your conjectures after sessions of intuitive reasoning; and then you use axioms and theorems to solidify their truth. It's like putting the rebar in the concrete.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your second question: No, that theorem is not sufficient. You can of course get $[0,1)$ by taking away the element $1$ from $[0,1]$, and of course $[0,1]$ is trivially homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. But then, all the theorem tells you is that you can take an element away from $[0,1]$ so that you get a set homeomorphic to $[0,1)$ — but you already knew that: Taking the element $1$ away does that. Nowhere does the theorem say that $y\ne x$. Nor does the theorem say that there exists *more* than one such element. And indeed, in the general case there may not exist a second one. Consider taking away $0$ from $[0,1)$ to get $(0,1)$; there's no other element you can take away from $[0,1)$ to get a set homeomorphic to $(0,1)$.

The easiest (and I believe, for this specific problem the only) way to prove the sets to be homeomorphic is to explicitly construct a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Just try drawing their cartesian product [0,1)x(0,1] in the plane and connecting the upper left corner with the lower right corner. That subset of their product is a continuous bijection with a continuous inverse.

Always reason about these problems geometrically. You can't pull proofs out of thin air. They have to come from somewhere. Use your intuition about the concepts.